# Android - Login HTTP works API 10 Only

Tags: android, cookies, httpurlconnection

To get some information, my app emulates the behaviour of a web browser. The log-in session of the target website has 3 steps:

1. Access the form (gives a cookie for authentication)
2. Send a POST request with all information
3. The server answers contains a link in the headers that indicates the address to go to

I have three functions for that, one that gets the page and extracts the session Cookie.
The second one extracts the form of this first page and puts the right infos.
The third one prepares the POST request, sends it, and read the Location in the headers.

**It works fine... But with API 10 only.......**
Does anyone know what has changed after API 10??

I've tried on Emulators with API 13 or more, and at the moment of sending the POST request, the server answers as if the Cookie given in the first page is not valid. (I get an answer Code of 200, and the login page... Instead of a 302 answer and the Location to follow).

I use the java.net CookieManager & CookieHandler

Here is the first function for example:

```
    private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // default is GET
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // act like a browser
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");

        if (MainActivity.cookies != null) {
            for (String cookie : MainActivity.cookies) {
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            }
        }

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // Get the response cookies
        setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

        return response.toString();

      }
```

And this is the third function (nothing special in the second one:

```
    private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // Acts like a browser
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");

        for (String cookie : MainActivity.cookies) {
            System.out.println("Adding Cookie: "+cookie);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }


        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

        // Update Progress bar -> 25
                    mProgression += 5;
                    msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(PROGRESSION, mProgression, 0);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Send post request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(postParams);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);


        System.out.println("Attempt to get location");

        // Get the location of the ticket in the ResponseHeader
        setLocation(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Location"));    



        // Get the Cookie of the ResponseHeader AFTER sending credentials
        setLoginCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

        BufferedReader in = 
                 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        // System.out.println(response.toString());

      }
```

There is no problem with the log cat, the third function can't go past the "get("Location")" since the server doesn't return any location...

Thanks to whoever takes time to answer that one...
Btw, it's my first app :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a better client that will handle all the headers and the body by itself, you can use android built in [HTTP client](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) but it can not persist cookies, or you can use [loopj async client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) that works great.
Actually I published a post that explained how we did it, you can read it [here](http://noamsh.com/2013/08/30/login-and-cookies/).